# C# OutOfMemoryException on array

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm quite new into C# and right now I'm totally stuck into this function.
Any help would be appreciated.

I'm getting an OutOfMemoryException on  `mess.Add(firstname);`
I'm pretty sure it's because of an array fault but I can't seem to make it work.

Who can guide me in the right way?

This is my code so far:

```
 public List<string> SelectEmployee(string pkrelation)
        {
        SDKRecordset inboundSet = IQSDK.CreateRecordset("R_CONTACT", "", "FK_RELATION = " + pkrelation, "");
        inboundSet.MoveFirst();
        string person = inboundSet.Fields["FK_PERSON"].Value.ToString();
        messages.Add(person);

        inboundSet.MoveNext();
        SDKRecordset inboundSet2 = IQSDK.CreateRecordset("R_PERSON", "", "PK_R_PERSON = " + person, "");


        if (inboundSet2 != null && inboundSet2.RecordCount > 0)
        {
            inboundSet2.MoveFirst();              

            do
            {
                string firstname = inboundSet2.Fields["FIRSTNAME"].Value.ToString();
                mess.Add(firstname);

                inboundSet.MoveNext();
            }
            while (!inboundSet2.EOF);
            return mess;


        }

        messages.Add("Error, didn't work.");
        return messages;// null;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many records are in your `inboundSet2`? Are you sure the `EOF` is hit after a reasonable number of iterations? EDIT: Do you have a typo? Shouldn't it be `inboundSet2.MoveNext()`, not `inboundSet.MoveNext()`?

Comment: In that vein, see if it works with really small recordsets, like 10 and 10. If the error *still* occurs, you're clearly dealing with a loop that never exits or something similar. #basictroubleshooting

Comment: What is `mess`? The same as `messages`? Are you clearing it somewhere?

Comment: I think you want inboundSet2.MoveNext() in your loop

Comment: +1 for inboundSet2.MoveNext() otherwise while(!inboundSet2.EOF) may never be true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo. You accidentally have `inboundSet.MoveNext()` so naturally your `inboundSet2.EOF` is never set to `false` because you never actually iterate through it. This causes an infinite loop eventually hitting the `OutOfMemoryException`.

```
do
{
    string firstname = inboundSet2.Fields["FIRSTNAME"].Value.ToString();
    mess.Add(firstname);

    inboundSet.MoveNext(); // This needs to be inboundSet2!
}
while(!inboundSet2.EOF) //EOF never becomes true causing an infinite loop
```

Comment: Thanks guys! This was the problem, guess I need some more coffee !

Comment: @Marijke Might I also suggest some better variable naming along with the coffee. For example `contactInboundSet` and `personInboundSet` instead of `inboundSet` and `inboundSet2` :) Would have been immediately obvious something was wrong (and more likely than not, _never_ wrote/used the wrong set in the first place)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, that's a perfect idea!